# MLFlow Projects throw JSONDecode error when run

Tags: mlflow

I'm trying to get MLFlow Projects to run using the MLFlow CLI and its following the tutorial leads to an error.  For any project I try to run from the CLI, I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rbc/.local/bin/mlflow", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
  File "/home/rbc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 764, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/rbc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 717, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/rbc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1137, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/home/rbc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 956, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/home/rbc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 555, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/rbc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mlflow/cli.py", line 139, in run
    run_id=run_id,
  File "/home/rbc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mlflow/projects/__init__.py", line 230, in run
    storage_dir=storage_dir, block=block, run_id=run_id)
  File "/home/rbc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mlflow/projects/__init__.py", line 88, in _run
    active_run = _create_run(uri, experiment_id, work_dir, entry_point)
  File "/home/rbc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mlflow/projects/__init__.py", line 579, in _create_run
    active_run = tracking.MlflowClient().create_run(experiment_id=experiment_id, tags=tags)
  File "/home/rbc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mlflow/tracking/client.py", line 101, in create_run
    source_version=source_version
  File "/home/rbc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mlflow/store/rest_store.py", line 156, in create_run
    response_proto = self._call_endpoint(CreateRun, req_body)
  File "/home/rbc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mlflow/store/rest_store.py", line 66, in _call_endpoint
    js_dict = json.loads(response.text)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Here's an example of the type of command I'm using to start the run, which comes directly from the tutorial

```
mlflow run https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow#examples/sklearn_elasticnet_wine -m databricks -c cluster-spec.json --experiment-id 72647065958042 -P alpha=2.0 -P l1_ratio=0.5
```

I've traced the error to something involving MLFLow returning empty when it tries to start a run but I can successfully run MLFlow experiments using the Databricks environment I'm connecting to so I'm not sure where the problem is, I'm running MLFlow 0.9.1 on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: I wonder whether it is because of your python3. Can you try with  python2?

Comment: similar problem here, but slightly different error message. I know it's authentication issue, because my message says something like this: mlflow.exceptions.MlflowException: API request to endpoint was successful but the response body was not in a valid JSON format. Response body: '<!doctype html><html><head><meta charset="utf-8"/><meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en"/><title>Databricks - Sign In

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you have solved your issue, but here is how I fixed it:

1. the databricks-cli work with the following config without problem:

   ```
   host = https://xxx.databricks.net/?o=<org_id>
   token=dapixxx
   ```
2. but mlflow not quit happy about that, change it to:

   ```
   host = https://xxx.databricks.net
   username = token
   password = dapixxx
   ```